# How to execute python cgi script?

Tags: python, cgi

My server supports Python 2.7. It is located under **/usr/bin/python2.7**.

What do I have to take care of when trying to execute a cgi script ? I don't want to use Django or anything like that. I **only** want the script to be running and the text that was printed within the script to be shown as it was an html file.

```
print """<html>
<body>
Hi !
</body>
</html>"""
```

should be simply shown as

```
Hi !
```

in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a CGI script to run you have to setup your webserver to run the CGI scripts.

It pretty much depends on the server you are running:

[CGI and Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html) explains the basics for CGI and apache.

Another good resource is probably the web programming guide in the python documentation:
[Python web programming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming)

Comment: The first link was exactly what I searched for ! Thank you.